# Converting tab to print preview, but no gui

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to convert a tab to a print preview thing. I am successfully turning to print preview like this:

```
function noida_printpreview(aWindow) {
    var wbp = aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebBrowserPrint);
    var listener = {
        onLocationChange: function(webProgress, request, location, flags) {},
        onProgressChange: function(webProgress, request, curSelfProgress, maxSelfProgress, curTotalProgress, maxTotalProgress) {},
        onSecurityChange: function(webProgress, request, state) {},
        onStateChange: function(webProgress, request, stateFlags, status) {},
        onStatusChange: function(webProgress, request, status, message) {},
        QueryInterface: function(iid) {
            if (iid.equals(Ci.nsIWebProgressListener) || iid.equals(Ci.nsISupportsWeakReference)) {
                return this;
            }
            throw Cr.NS_NOINTERFACE;
        }
    }
    Services.prefs.setBoolPref('print.show_print_progress', false);
    //XXX I would have thought this would work, instead I'm forced to use prefs service
    wbp.globalPrintSettings.showPrintProgress = false;
    wbp.printPreview(wbp.globalPrintSettings, aWindow, listener);
    Services.prefs.clearUserPref('print.show_print_progress');
}
```

If you copy paste that to scratchpad, then do:

```
noida_printpreview(content)
```

You'll see it turn to print preview, but it has no buttons to go to print dialog, or even close. And back button doesn't work anymore.

Can you help me to figure why its so quirky like this.

Thanks

Comment: Please be a bit more clear as to what you are attempting to accomplish.  Are you attempting to initiate a normal print preview of a tab/window? Are you attempting to do anything special, other than just a standard print preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting to initiate a Print Preview then you can do the following:

```
function noida_printpreview(aWindow) {
    aWindow.document.getElementById("cmd_printPreview").doCommand();
}
```

A print can be initiated with:

```
function noida_print(aWindow) {
    aWindow.document.getElementById("cmd_print").doCommand();
}
```

These use the built in Firefox commands to perform a Print, or Print Preview. Using the built in [command interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Commands). They should be a bit more future-proof than hard coding it yourself (they are an intended abstraction so that it "can be invoked without needing to know about the details of its implementation."

I use both of these in my Firefox add-on [Print Button is Print](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-button-is-print/) which changes the print button back to actually being a print button, with the Print Preview functionality available with <kbd>shift</kbd>-click and/or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-click.

The [Print Button is Print](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-button-is-print/) add-on uses the following function to perform either a Print or a Print-Preview when the print button is clicked:

```
const extensionPrefs  = "extensions." + "PrintButtonIsPrint";

function handlePrintButton(event) {
    var window = event.view;
    let commandId = "cmd_print";

    if(
        (event.ctrlKey
            && (!Services.prefs.prefHasUserValue(extensionPrefs + ".printPreview.ctrl")
                || Services.prefs.getBoolPref(extensionPrefs + ".printPreview.ctrl")))
        || (event.shiftKey
            && (!Services.prefs.prefHasUserValue(extensionPrefs + ".printPreview.shift")
                || Services.prefs.getBoolPref(extensionPrefs + ".printPreview.shift")))
    ) {
        //The user can enable/disable being able to use shift and/or ctrl-click via 
        //  the add-on's option dialog.
        commandId = "cmd_printPreview";
    }
    let printCommand = window.document.getElementById(commandId);
    try {
        printCommand.doCommand();
    } catch (e) {
        //The doCommand() causes an exception on Linux, but doing the exact same thing
        //  as the command does work.  I assume this is because of the scope of the 
        //  window variable.
        //Having this explicitly done here will require this to be changed if the method
        //  of calling the print command changes instead of any such changes automatically
        //  being incorporated by using the "cmd_print".
        //Note: We try a print command here even if it is a preview which failed.
        PrintUtils.print(window.gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentWindowAsCPOW,
                             window.gBrowser.selectedBrowser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks very much Mayken! These methods seem to print the currently focused tab. Ideally, the iframe i want to print, is one i have appended to `Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow`. I send that straight to the printer with this code here: https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/bootstrap.js#L1168-L1190 is there anyway to send that hidden iframe to a print preview tab in any given 'navigator:browser'?

Comment: Hey @mayken can you please see the solution i posted here, its not a solution but a work in progress using the `PrintPreviewListener` object to change the `getSourceBrowser` to that of the iframe, and leave the `getPrintPreviewBrowser` untouched so it uses the window to show the print preview, can you please help me knock that one out.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Posting this work in progress to show @Mayken so he can help, this is copy pasteable to scratchpad.</strike>

This uses this technique:

```
            let b = window.gBrowser, pT = b.selectedTab;
            b.getBrowserForTab((b.selectedTab = b.addTab(canvas.toDataURL("image/png")))).addEventListener("load", function() {
                this.removeEventListener("load", arguments.callee, true);
                let l = window.PrintPreviewListener, e = l.onExit;
                l.onExit = function() {
                    e.call(l);
                    b.removeCurrentTab();
                    b.selectedTab = pT;
                    l.onExit = e;
                };
                window.PrintUtils.printPreview(l);
            }, true );
```

See it passes in a print preview listener object, and we can temporarily override it, then restore on exit. Looking at the source on dxr:

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser.js#3217

It shows that we have `getSourceBrowser` which is in comment stated as:

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/printing/content/printUtils.js#159

> Returns the  that contains the document being printed. This  must have its type attribute set to "content", "content-targetable", or "content-primary"

```
        var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'); //Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;
        var doc = win.document;
        var iframe = doc.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'iframe');
        win.nsif = iframe;
        iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
            iframe.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, true);

            var aPPListener = win.PrintPreviewListener;
            var aOrigPPgetSourceBrowser = aPPListener.getSourceBrowser;
            aPPListener.getSourceBrowser = function() {
                var asettime = win.setTimeout(function() {
                    aPPListener.getSourceBrowser = aOrigPPgetSourceBrowser;
                    win.alert('ok restored getSourceBrowser');
                }, 5000);
                return iframe.contentWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation);
            };
            win.PrintUtils.printPreview(aPPListener);

        }, true); // if i use false here it doesnt work
        iframe.setAttribute('src', 'data:text,html,this is test text');
        // iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
        doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframe); // src page wont load until i append to document
```

The problem is, its not entering print preview. This should work, as im setting the`getSourceBrowser` to that of the iframe. The error I get is:

> [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIWebBrowserPrint.printPreview]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/browser-content.js :: enterPrintPreview :: line 469"  data: no] browser-content.js:473:0
>   TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter browser-content.js:585:9

## EDIT - holy heck i got it to print an iframe to print preview!!

Copy paste solution to scratchpad!

```
    var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'); //Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow;
    var doc = win.document;
    var iframe = doc.createElement('browser');
    win.nsif = iframe;
    iframe.addEventListener('load', function() {
        iframe.removeEventListener('load', arguments.callee, true);

        var aPPListener = win.PrintPreviewListener;
        var aOrigPPgetSourceBrowser = aPPListener.getSourceBrowser;
        aPPListener.getSourceBrowser = function() {
            var asettime = win.setTimeout(function() {
                aPPListener.getSourceBrowser = aOrigPPgetSourceBrowser;
                win.alert('ok restored getSourceBrowser');
            }, 5000);
            return iframe;
        };
        win.PrintUtils.printPreview(aPPListener);

    }, true); // if i use false here it doesnt work
    iframe.setAttribute('type', 'content');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', 'data:text,html,this is test text');
    doc.documentElement.appendChild(iframe); // src page wont load until i append to document
```

Comment: Wow, further thought i can open a new window and make the print preview from any window go to that window, its amazing!